# Undefined function 'loadjson' for input arguments of type 'char'. Function does not work

Tags: json, matlab

I want to load data saved in .json format. The files are actually saved like this:

ph02-flanker-level1-block0-2014-05-16_17/32/16 etc.

when reading them into the directory they look like this:

ph02-flanker-level1-block0-2014-05-16_17:32:16 for some reason.

I am using mac which realizes the data as unix, so, there is no .json ending or the like…

That's not the main problem however, the loadjson function does not work anymore (It used to a couple of months ago…)

This is the code I used:

```
data = loadjson('ph10-flanker-level1-block0-2014-05-16_17/33/42');
data = cell2mat(data); 

congruent = [data(:).congruent]'; 
result = [data(:).result]';
response_time = [data(:).response_time]';
```

The error message is:

> Undefined function 'loadjson' for input arguments of type 'char'.

The strange thing is, this actually used to work a couple of months ago. 
Perhaps somebody has an idea. Thanks a lot in advance.

Clem

Comment: have you searched for a file called `loadjson.m` on your machine? maybe you deleted/renamed it by accident

Comment: Do you have the function in your path?

Answer (score 1):

`loadjson` is not a native function of Matlab, it's one that you downloaded most likely from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files-in-matlab-octave/content/jsonlab/loadjson.m).

You need to make sure your script has access to the file either by pasting it in your MATLAB search path or the current folder or using the [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) function.

From Matlab's manual on functions:

> Save the file (in this example, loadjson.m), either in the current folder
>   or in a folder on the MATLAB search path. MATLAB looks for programs in
>   these specific locations.

Comment: I can confirm this is true.  `loadjson` is part of the `jsonlab` package that's on the MATLAB File Exchange.  This is not a native MATLAB function, and I use this quite heavily where I work.  However, `loadjson` calls other functions that are part of that package, so it's highly recommended you just download the entire package and add it to your MATLAB search path as per Jigg's instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just moved the jsonlab folder so matlab could not find it anymore. It is back in the path now.

Comment: For some strange reason, however, I am getting this error message: Undefined function or variable "data".

Error in loadjson (line 75)
jsoncount=length(data);

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I use a loop through all the files in my directory, or directly write the filename. The files basically look as mentioned above. Maybe it has something to do with the formatting?

Comment: @user3591980 you're welcome. If my answer was helpful, you can (but don't have to) accept it by clicking the checkmark button. Once you have enough reputation you can also up-vote the answers that you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

the problem actually was that matlab did not find the function. Secondly, the files I was tying to load were actually empty. For some reason. So, when the file is empty no format can be realized which likely caused the error message.

Cheers, 
Clem